# Testing Laravel Cached Routes

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-routing

I ran into an issue where Laravel's cached routes were not the same as uncached, so I am attempting to write a unit test which compares the two.

```php
    /** @test */
    public function cached_and_uncached_are_identical()
    {
        Artisan::call('route:clear');
        Artisan::call('route:list', ['--compact' => true]);
        $uncached = Artisan::output();

        Artisan::call('route:cache');
        Artisan::call('route:list', ['--compact' => true]);
        $cached = Artisan::output();

        $this->assertSame($cached, $uncached);
    }
```

The call to `route:list` after `route:cache` throws a `LogicException`: "Route is not bound."

I don't get that error when executing those commands on the command line. My searches haven't turned up any good hints for tracking down the issue.

How do I find the issue and fix it?

Comment: I think you should not be testing this, as you are testing the framework, and you do not have to do that. Why are you testing the routes' cache ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Because I had a case with route macros where there was a difference. This unit test would be to check for regressions.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what was happening ? Maybe there is a way to test this but not how you are trying to

Comment: @matiaslauriti - Some of the code is proprietary. I will have to create a minimal working example to demonstrate it.